Confusing FM with CDMA
Frequency modulation (FM) causes expansion in the frequency domain, an expansion which is beneficial in terms of signal SNR.
Direct Sequence Spread Spectrum or CDMA causes expansion in frequency domain as well, an expansion which benefits signal to interference ratio as long as the codes are orthogonal or SNR (signal vs noise ratio) after decorrelation and filtering.
Since both modulations result in frequency expansion, i.e. there is a trade off between signal quality and spectral efficiency are  there any similarities between them? Is there a way one can look at CDMA through the prism of FM or as a kind of improved FM or are they completely different from each other and completely unrelated?

The two concepts are independent and orthogonal. You can even apply CDMA to an FM signal in order to convert it to spread-spectrum.
FM's advantages come from the ability to reject AM at the receiver and still recover the original baseband signal.
CDMA's advantages come from the "gain" that the receiver's despreading operation has on the original signal, relative to interference in the channel.

As Dave says, they're pretty much completely unrelated: DSSS is, in the end, something that you apply to each symbol of the signal to be spreaded independently, with what you do next being independent of what input you saw before.
FM, on the other hand, is dependent on the history of what input came before.
They share no mathematical similarities in where the information resides, either.

Frequency modulation (FM) causes expansion in the frequency domain, an expansion which is beneficial in terms of signal SNR.

Such statements are to be taken with a very solid amount of skepticism. That is only true if the noise (both in how it's spectrally distributed and on which power it has relative to the carrier of interest) fulfills specific assumptions. Generally, no, that expansion is not beneficial to SNR – that's just a power ratio – because expanding your transmission's bandwidth means that you also get more bandwidth in which you capture noise. If any processing gain is to be won, then by undoing that expansion at the receiver, in a way that attenuates noise more than signal. For DSSS, as long as synchronizable, that works at any SNR. For an FM receiver, that only works for relatively high SNRs to begin with; for low SNRs, not having applied frequency modulation is worse than having directly modulated the amplitude of a narrowband carrier.
In other words: always check your assumptions on the signal and the noise, when you see something improving SNR!

Both FM and CDMA/DSSS involve frequency expansion, but their underlying mechanisms and objects are quite different. FM is continuous-phase frequency modulation technique. It modulates the frequency of a carrier signal in direct proportion to the amplitude of the input signal. The primary goal of frequency expansion is improvising signal quality (SNR) and resistance to noice especially for analog signals like voice or music. However, CDMA/DSSS uses a spread spectrum digital modulation technique where the data signal is multiplied by a high-rate pseudorandom sequence to spread the signal across a much wider frequency band. Its frequency expansion is aimed at achieving multiple access and improving resistance to interference, especially in environments with many concurrent signals.
